# Reporting from Background Thread Using IProgress<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.5, async-await, progress

All, I have an expensive task which I undertake using the `async`/`await` keywords under .NET4.5. I report progress from the background thread via the [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh193692.aspx) class.

The object I pass into `IProgress<T>` as the type is `ProgressInfo` which I create as a singleton class to avoid the overhead of creating and disposing of this type of object a great number of times during a run. The class is

```
public class ProgressInfo : IDisposable
{
    public static ProgressInfo instance = null;
    public WorkbookProgressInfo workbookinfo { get; set; }
    public string progressMessage { get; set; }
    public int progressPercentage { get; set; }

    // Default constructor which has a few overloads 
    // for the class members above.
    protected ProgressInfo()
    {
    }
    ...

    // The default instance creator for the class. 
    // This also has overloads to allow changes to the 
    // class variables.
    public static ProgressInfo Instance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new ProgressInfo();
        return instance;
    }
    ...
}
```

I report the progress via the method `ReportProgress` and set up my `IProgress<ProgressInfo>` as

```
IProgress<CostEngine.ProgressInfo> progressIndicator =
    new Progress<CostEngine.ProgressInfo>(ReportProgress);
```

and reporting from the background thread is typically done using a global `ProgressInfo progressInfo` and global `IProgress<ProgressInfo> progressIndicator` like

```
...
progressInfo = new ProgressInfo.Instance(workbookinfo, message, n);
progressIndicator.Report(progressInfo);
...
```

The problem is that for runs that are small and execute quickly the `ProgressInfo` object passed in to `ReportProgress` changes as `ReportProgress` is executing, so I test

```
if (progressInfo.workbookinfo != null)
{
    // Do stuff <- here progressInfo.workbookinfo is changing to null!
}
```

**How can I avoid this issue whilst keeping the expense of reporting the progress at a minimum?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Using a singleton in this scenario seems to be *very, very* odd. For starters, your `ProgressInfo` class is not thread-safe. I wouldn't do that and you shouldn't either. Have you actually verified that the creation of the `ProgressInfo` instances is a performance problem? Or do you just think that *it could be one*?

Comment: I just think it could be one. I am reporting from large nested loops and creating these (allbeit fairly lightweight) objects thousands of times (depending on the run) seems to be to be an overhead I can avoid by using a Singleton... I am also not sure how the fact that `Progressinfo` is not thread safe, has any bearing on this problem as the synchronisation context is fully handled in the use of `IProgress<T>`. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Very bad idea. You will create far bigger overheads by trying to make this class thread-safe with all the locking etc. What you are doing here is premature optimization. Nothing good ever comes from it. Optimize what you have verified to be a problem using a profiler.

Comment: The fact that `workbookinfo` is changing to `null` is demonstrating pretty good that your class is not thread safe. The synchronization context has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Create ProgressInfo every time and not to use singletone. To increase berformance just try to reduce count of progres notifying

Comment: Thanks @DanielHilgarth. So woudld you recommend creating an instance of this class each time I wish to report back to the UI thread? Or, could I create a deep copy of the `ProgressInfo` object in my `ReportProgress` method and work on that? If you are reccommending creating a new `Progressinfo` object each time I report, how can I ensure that the creation of many of these obejects is as light weight as possible?

Comment: @Killercam: A deep copy is a new instance, so that is the same as creating a new one. And yes, that's what I recommend. Object creation is lightweight, I don't know what "more light" you need. If it will ever be a problem, you should reduce the number of progress reports. The real bottle neck you will get is not from the object creation but from trying to display all these thousands changes in the UI. Updating the UI takes a *lot* more time than creating a new object instance.

Comment: I just saw the last comment. @gabba thanks for your time. Daniel, you state the use of a singleton here is odd; I agree, however, it clearly serves a purpose - to keep the expense of object creation to an absolute minimum.

Comment: Right, cheers Daniel. Your advice is much appreciated. If you want to cobble together and answer I will gladly accept it... And I am open to arguments. I am a novice.

Comment: @Killercam: Added an answer. It focuses on a solution, not on what you currently have. I guess that has been discussed in depth in the comments here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to optimize the wrong part of your application here.

Several thousand objects are nothing for an application. Creating them most likely won't be a performance problem in your application. However, what *could* be a problem is the updating of the UI. If those thousands of progress reports are happening in a short period of time, you will update your UI constantly. Updating the UI costs time, so if you will run into a bottle neck, it will be here.

The correct approach here is to only report what you need to report.
For example, when you have 60.000 iterations that happen in - let's say - a minute and you report every single one of these iterations, you will try to update the UI *every millisecond*.
Do you really need *1000 FPS* for your progress bar? I doubt it.
It would be perfectly good to only report every second.  However, reporting every second creates it's own kind of overhead.

What I am doing in my applications is to report as soon as the percentage changed.
That would result in a maximum of 100 reports, no matter how many iterations you actually have.
In the above example I would report every 600 iterations.

To simplify this, I actually created a class called `ProgressReporter`.
In its constructor, it takes a factory delegate that creates the `ProgressInfo` object and the total number of iterations.
It provides a `ReportProgress` method you pass in the current iteration.
The class internally stores the previously reported percentage and when calling this method it calculates the new percentage. Only if the differ will it use the factory delegate to create the new `ProgressInfo` and call `Report` on the `IProgress<T>` instance.

BTW: If your background operation doesn't take minutes but hours, you can change this to not report when the percentage changed but when the first or second decimal of the percentage changed.
The point here is: Find an amount of reports that gives the user a feedback every few seconds.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you time is much appreciated. I actually perfom a UI update mod (1000 records) and it can take several ms to process a record, so I am not overwhelming the UI. I have already tested you suggestion and there is absolutely no effect on performance (if we take the default time scale as seconds). Again thanks. All the best and have a good weekend.

Comment: @Killercam: If there is no effect on performance it means that your worries were unjustified right from the start :) That's exactly the reason why you should only optimize what you have measured. Otherwise you will very often optimize at the wrong place - and sometimes even make things worse.

Comment: Good advice... Trying to second guess what the CLR will do performance wise is a bit silly.